# Django-forms: Raise forms.ValidationError not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am beginner in Django and recently studied form-validation. I implemented the code but was unable to raise ValidationError for some constraints.

Here are my subsequent file content.

**forms.py**

```python
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


class formClass(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    catchBot = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                           validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(formClass, self).clean()
        t = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if t[0].lower() != 'd':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Name must start with d.')
        return cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from formApp import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def formNameView(request):
    formObj = forms.formClass()
    formDict = {'form': formObj}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formObj = forms.formClass(request.POST)

        if formObj.is_valid():
            # SOME CODE
            print("NAME: " + formObj.cleaned_data['name'])
            print("EMAIL: " + formObj.cleaned_data['email'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/users')
    return render(request, 'formApp/forms.html', context=formDict)
```

My valid input works great, but it doesn't happen with my invalid input.

for example: if `name = 'Alex'`, it should raise an error. But it doesn't.
Could someone please help me in it?

**EDIT:**

**[Added forms.html and validators callable.]**

Previously, I used `validators` callable to raise ValidationError instead of `clean()` method. But the results were same. 
Here is my code:

```
def checkForD(value):
    if value[0].lower() != 'd':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Name must start with d.')
.
.
.
# in my formClass()
name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, validators[checkForD])
...
```

**Forms.html**

```
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='jumbotron'>
    <h3>Welcome to the form page.</h3>
    <h2>Please insert the form.</h2>
  </div>
  <form method="post">
    {{form.as_p}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does happen? Does it still print the name and email?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes it does on console, but just for valid input. The code is working good, but it is not showing ValidationError on my web page. Just for the confirmation, I used validators instead of clean method, but still the problem persists.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just for ease, I am uploading a template of my webpage. I think it won't be of any use, but still, I should provide you my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST block you've redefined `formObj` to be the bound form, but you haven't replaced the instance in the context dict - so what is passed to the template is the empty unbound form, and no errors will be shown on that template.

The easiest fix would be to move the definition of the dict to the end of the function:

```
formDict = {'form': formObj}
return render(request, 'formApp/forms.html', context=formDict)
```

Now the correct instance will be used and the errors will show.

Comment: It worked! Just a silly mistake. I think it's a good approach to use context dict without initialising it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: don't define the formDict in post, directly define it in return render

```py
return render(request, 'formApp/forms.html', {'form': formObj})
```